# How to launch a batch file in the same window?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am working on a launcher that contains batch games. The batch file of the launcher and of the game are in the same folder. Like I said they are both .bat files. So it is obviuos that I can just run `filename` or `./filename.bat`. But running that in an existing bat file opens it in a new window.

**How can I make it so that it runs the batch file in the same command window?** I already tried stuff like:

```
cmd /k file.bat
start /B file.bat
start file.bat
file
file.bat
```

Comment: Could you try `call programname.bat` ? On my system, it works just by using program name ...

Comment: @S.Brottes Sadly. This closes the window and opens the script in a new one.

Comment: call should work. Have you set a setting to launch scripts in a new process? Or is your script doing something funky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it, is by using `call batch.bat`.

If that doesn't work on your end, then your script is doing something odd, or there is a setting configured to run batch files in their own process.

Here's an example:

**test.bat:**

```
echo test
call test2
pause
```

**test2.bat:**

```
echo test2
pause
```

The screenshot below is the output of calling test.bat:
[image]

Comment: Well, the script that im trying to run contains an mode setting (window size) and just creates an loading bar

Comment: Something on your system or in your code is making it not work. Its impossible for us to figure out what it is as you did not post your code, so I only respond to what should work, and its up to you to figure out the rest unless you also share your code.

Comment: @LPChip Is correct, **call** is the command to do what you need. If this is not working, then something is wrong with the child script Most likely the window size code.